# Fill a list with a for loop python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iterator

Mine is not really a problem but the search for a solution, if any. And knowing this language necessarily exists. I have an integer 'n' and an integer 'p'. What I'm trying to do is divide n into digits, raise them to p and put them in a list. Later I will sum () the list. (Below is the code)

`tot = sum([int(x)**p for x in str(n)])`

The code works perfectly without any problems, the only thing I miss to add is that at each iteration, 'p' must be increase by 1. I have tried many things, and looked at a few other methods, but cannot find the correct syntax for adding this step.
I really hope that some of you can help me find this solution.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you share what your `n` and `p` currently looks like? What is your current output and what is your desired output?

Comment: So while `n` is an integer, it's parsed as single values in this case. Is that right? Any reason why it isn't a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get an index which you can use to increase `p` by:

```
tot = sum([int(x) ** (p + i) for i, x in enumerate(str(n))])
```

If you want to start at `p + 1` instead of `p + 0`, use

```
tot = sum([int(x) ** (p + i) for i, x in enumerate(str(n), start=1)])
```

BTW, you don't even need to create the list. Remove the brackets to save some memory:

```
tot = sum(int(x) ** (p + i) for i, x in enumerate(str(n)))
```

Comment: Nice! I thought of using a `zip()` option

Comment: @astrochun It works (`sum(int(x) ** (p + i) for i, x in zip(range(len(str(n))), str(n)))`) but adds an unnecessary level of abstraction

Comment: Right it's more complicated hence why I like your solution more. I forgot about `enumerate`.

Comment: Thanks so much. For the matter of removing the list I did the same thing, only in the code I passed I hadn't removed it yet. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) inside your *list comprehension*  to achieve this as:

```
>>> n = 12345
>>> p = 2

>>> sum([int(x)**(p+i) for i, x in enumerate(str(n))])
16739
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple containing a count (from `start` which defaults to `0`) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

You can pass *start* as `1`, if you want to start with `p+1` as:

```
>>> sum([int(x)**(p+i) for i, x in enumerate(str(n), start=1)])
82481
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution based on a for loop should be

```
tot = []

p = <whatever>

for x in str(n):
   temp = int(x) ** p 
   tot.append(temp)
   p = p + 1

sum(tot)
```